# Registering my custom modal.js conflicts with Wordpress Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, enqueue

I noticed that some buttons stopped working in my theme so I started debugging and found the issue to be with my modal script registration.

Please can somebody tell me how this is causing an issue?  I have registered and enqueued several other files just fine in the same way.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scripts' ) );
}

function scripts() {

        wp_register_script( 'modal_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/modal.js', array( 'jquery'), NULL, false );
        wp_register_style( 'modal_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'css/modal.css');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'modal_script' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'modal_css');
}
```

and the modal.js file which is causing the conflict (or the way I am registering/enqueuing):

```
    (function ($) {

    "use strict";

$(document).ready(function () {
var my_modal_modal = document.querySelector(".my-modal-modal");
var my_modal_trigger = document.querySelector(".my-modal-trigger");
var my_modal_closeButton = document.querySelector(".my-modal-close-button");

function my_modal_toggleModal() {
    my_modal_modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function my_modal_windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === my-modal-modal) {
        my_modal_toggleModal();
    }
}

my_modal_trigger.addEventListener("click", my_modal_toggleModal);
my_modal_closeButton.addEventListener("click", my_modal_toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", my_modal_windowOnClick);

})
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT:
Console output:**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
>       at HTMLDocument. (modal.js:21)
>       at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)

**UPDATED: SOLVED**

Well after narrowing it down to 2 lines of code I just decided to re-write the triggers in jQuery and it worked.  I think I will continue to re-write the whole file to tidy it up.

Comment: Did the buttons that stopped working have any of the classes in your modal JS, e.g. 'modal' or 'close-button'

Comment: Unfortunately no: class="wait-for-click"

There may be other things not working due to this conflict, perhaps I should go ahead and rename everything anyway just to be safe.

Comment: Instead of the event listener on `window` at the end, can you just put that on `modal` directly, i.e. `modal.addEventListener("click", toggleModal)`? All the windowOnClick appears to be doing is checking it it's target is the `modal` variable anyway.

Comment: No I can't.  My modal contains an ajax form so the user needs to click a button within the modal.  Doing that just closes it. I edited the code and changed all the names in the above modal code just to avoid naming issues.

Comment: Ok, it seems starting from the bottom-up.  After commenting out these two lines, the buttons work again:
//my_modal_trigger.addEventListener("click", my_modal_toggleModal);
//my_modal_closeButton.addEventListener("click", my_modal_toggleModal);